How do I send emails with Python via Outlook, now that Microsoft has disabled SMTP auth?
Within the last few weeks, Microsoft has disabled SMTP auth for personal (free) Outlook.  My simple script no longer works using the smtplib, and email libraries to send emails via my Outlook account to another account.
Is there an alternative to STMP that I'm not aware of that will work with Outlook's new security requirements?
Here is the login that used to work:
    # set up the SMTP server
    s = smtplib.SMTP(host=SMTP_HOST, port=SMTP_PORT)
    s.starttls()

    try:
        s.login(SMTP_USER, SMTP_PASSWORD)
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print("Failed logging in")
        return False

I already tried multiple times to authenticate with SMTP, however it no longer works.  This was described in an email from Microsoft that they were disabling SMTP.
Thanks for your time!
This is not similar to this question, as this is not regarding a corporate account and, therefore, cannot be enabled in the settings.

This question is similar to: SMTP Authentication error while while sending mail from outlook using python language. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Done, thank you

There is an answer showing how to use OAuth2

There is no good easy answer, unfortunately, short of setting up your own SMTP server.

Outlook REST api can auth use OAuth2 and do mail ops
Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started
And Python wrapper for Outlook REST api
https://pyoutlook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
